# Frequency Compensation Design

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply, pspice

I am trying to understand compensation using TPS40200 [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps40200.pdf), the flow is given in Page 26 to 30 of the document.

- This sentence is bit is irrelevant in Page 29, because `Kfb`feedback gain is already calculated previously as `11.4dB` the only remaining factor is error amplifier gain

[image] 
 - And later error amplifier gain including feedback is calculated using this formula [image]

How is this derived or seen? Is this closed loop gain which is desired to be `7.9dB`?

Comment: I am unsure what you are asking for ? Are you asking why amplifier and fb gain needs to be -7.9 dB or asking about the why the feedback gain is 11.4dB.

Comment: Since they are expecting overall gain to be 0dB at 35kHz error amplifier and feedback gain is to be 7.9dB, How is the later formula is derived or seen?